# Boost signals2 giving noncopyable errors

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, signals, boost-signals2

I'm currently working on a C++ application where I need to create a module that sends boost signals to another class. I'm using the Document-View example as a basis for my application (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#signals2.tutorial.document-view) , but I keep getting an error :

```
Error   1   error C2280: boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable(const   boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
```

This has me completely stumped - where does the error actually occur?

Build log is as follows :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: 32BitTrial, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  InboundLogicAdaptor.cpp
1>  main.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocmon(232): error C2280: 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable(const boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          C:\boost_1_58_0\boost/core/noncopyable.hpp(34) : see declaration of 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable'
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'boost::signals2::signal_base::signal_base(const boost::signals2::signal_base &)'
1>  OutboundLogicAdaptor.cpp
1>  TrialLogic.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

My main function is rather simple - I construct a GUI, a model for communicating with the GUI (TrialModel), a simple Logic that counts +1 every 500msec and an outbound logic adaptor, that is accessed via boost signals2 library from the Logic.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    TrialModel m;

    Trial w(0, &m);
    w.show();


    TrialLogic logic;

    OutboundLogicAdaptor adaptor(&m, logic);

    boost::thread t(logic);

    a.exec();

    t.join();

    return 1;

}
```

The logic class defines a signal that has one argument (integer) and an operator() for acting as a thread.

TrialLogic.h :

```
#pragma once

#include <boost\thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost\signals2.hpp>



class TrialLogic
{
public:
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void(int x)> signal_t;

    void operator()();
    TrialLogic();
    ~TrialLogic();

    boost::signals2::connection connect(const signal_t::slot_type &subscriber);

    void doubleIncrementSlot();

private:

    void emitSignal();

    signal_t signal;

    int testNum;

};
```

and the code itself :

```
#include "TrialLogic.h"

TrialLogic::TrialLogic()
{   
    testNum = 0;
}


TrialLogic::~TrialLogic()
{
}

boost::signals2::connection TrialLogic::connect(const signal_t::slot_type &subscriber){
    return signal.connect(subscriber);
}

void TrialLogic::operator()(){
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
    testNum++;
    emitSignal();

}

void TrialLogic::emitSignal(){
    signal_t(testNum);
}
```

And finally, the adaptor that receives the signal -

```
#include "OutboundLogicAdaptor.h"


OutboundLogicAdaptor::OutboundLogicAdaptor(TrialModel *modelHook, TrialLogic &logicHook) : logic(logicHook)
{
    this->hook = modelHook;

    signalConnection = logic.connect(boost::bind(&OutboundLogicAdaptor::transmitAngle, this, _1));
}



OutboundLogicAdaptor::~OutboundLogicAdaptor()
{
    signalConnection.disconnect();
}

void OutboundLogicAdaptor::transmitAngle(int angle){
    hook->postAngle(angle);
}
```

From my first inspection I cannot find anything that I've done wrong, but obviously there is a critical fault with my code. I'm pretty sure that the problem is not in the GUI side either, as I don't actually use any boost functions there and it worked fine before I tried to bind the system together.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reason for the failure:

Your `TrialLogic` class has a member of type `boost.signal` in it, and this type is not copiable (it is inherited from `signal_base`, which is inherited from `nocopyable`). This makes the class `TrialLogic` itself non-copyable. Yet you are trying to copy it here:

```
TrialLogic logic;
boost::thread t(logic);
```

`Boost.thread` accepts argument by value, so you are trying to copy something which is not copyable and the compiler is upset.

As for the solution, the easiest seems to be following: instead of defining `operator()` on your `TrialLogic`, define a function, than pass that function as well as a pointer or reference to the logic class. Something like that:

```
class TrialLogic
{
...
void launch() {
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
    testNum++;
    emitSignal();
}
};
...
// in main
boost::thread(&TrialLogic::launch, &logic);
```

Last, but not the least, I do not advise on using boost::thread. C++11 thread support is fully operational, and boost::thread doesn't really add any benefits.

Comment: Wow - that explains a lot! However, if I can't copy it, is there some way to run the thread without updating it?

Comment: @RainerKeerdo, I did provide one suggestion.

Comment: sorry, must've posted it when I was writing the comment! But yeah, I'll try to use the std::thread then - I've just always used boost threads in my previous projects.

Comment: @RainerKeerdo, std::thread vs boost::thread was more of the side comments. The real problem is with copy constructor, would be the same for std:: and boost::.